# Make compiler aware of NSView subclass methods when building ViewController's view programmatically

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, subclass, nsview

I have created a subclass of NSView that allows me to easily change the background color via the method `- (void)setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)aBackgroundColor`.

I want my view controller's main view to be this subclass, so I initiate it with `self.view = [[BetterNSView alloc] initWithFrame...`.

On the next line, I try to set its background color: `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]]`. But the compiler complains, saying that NSView doesn't have the method `setBackgroundColor`.

To solve this, I need to use typecasting: `[(BetterNSView *)self.view setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];`. That works. But I'd like to not need the typecasting.

How do I tell the compiler that the `view` property of the view controller is the `BetterNSView` subclass? Remember, I'm not using IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two reasonable choices.

1. Make an accessor on your view controller with the right type that just passes through to the `view` property.
2. Deal with the typecast.

Really, this is one of this situations where typecasting is okay.